# Bootstrap elements bleeding on smaller device sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

Something is weird with the margin/padding of the carousel. The container for the lorem text when resized automatically sizes into the navbar when on less than ~990px breakpoint.

This is not what I want intended for mobile devices. I'm unsure how to fix it either. I have a unique situation where I have a video playing in the background of essentially the carousel.

I tried adding padding to the body, that didn't fix it either.

```
<nav class="navbarWidth navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top position-fixed " aria-label="Eighth navbar example">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Website name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample07"
            aria-controls="navbarsExample07" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarsExample07">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end px-4">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/">lorem</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">lorem</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">lorem</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <Dropdown>Other Resources
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/"></a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">lorem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100 min-vh-100 ">
    <!-- <div id=""></div> -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel w-100 mb-6 " data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-theme="light">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active  ">
                <div id="video-container"></div>
                
                <script>var video = document.createElement("video");
                    video.src = "url.mp4 video";
                    video.preload = "auto";
                    video.muted = true;
                    video.autoplay = true;
                    video.loop = true;
                    video.addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
                        videoContainer = document.getElementById("video-container");
                        videoContainer.appendChild(video);
                        video.play();
                    });
                </script>

                <div class="carousel-caption text-start p-xxl-auto col-sm-6 col-lg mx-auto ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <h1 class="display-3 fw-normal text-white pt-5">NAME</h1> // Text that bleeds into the navbar
                            <h2 class="display-5 fw-normal lh-1 text-white">lorem</h2>
                            <h2 class="display-5 fw-normal lh-1 text-white">lorem</h2>
                            <br>
                            <p class="fs-3 text-white position-relative ">lorem
                            </p>
                            <p class="lead text-white"> lorem </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
                            <img src="../images/1.jpg" alt=""
                                class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto rounded-circle img-thumbnail " xmlns=""
                                role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
                                focusable="false">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I adjusted the body padding, the container padding/margins with different breakpoints.

What would be the best way to handle this problem?